# How and where to put passphrase of the Tessera private key when using Hashicorp vault

Tags: hashicorp-vault, quorum

We are using Quorum and Hashicorp vault in one of our systems. We have been able to successfully integrate these two i.e. we have put the Tessera private and public keys in the Vault and successfully ran the Quorum server.

The problem is, when we are trying to use passphrase for the private key, we could not find a way through which we can achieve this. Even we have observed that when we are using the tessera key generation tool for Hashicorp vault where it generates the keys and internally saves the same in the Vault as well, it does not ask for any passphrase. But when we use the normal key generation tool where it generates the keys and puts the same in the specified directory, it asks for the passphrase.

May you please help us how we can achieve this leveraging Hashicorp Vault and Tessera i.e. we generate a key pair where private is protected with passphrase.

We could not find any help in the Wiki and also we tried to analyze the source code and our impression is if we want to use passphrase protected private key for Tessera, we can't use Hashicorp Vault now.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tessera does not support the storing of passphrase-protected private keys in a Hashicorp Vault as Vault already encrypts the data that it stores.

However, to get access to the data stored in a Vault, the Tessera instance must possess the correct set of credentials (provided as environment variables) in order to authenticate with the Vault.  Using these credentials offers more flexibility and control in comparison to the passphrases used to secure file-stored keys.

For example, configuring an authentication method (e.g. AppRole authentication) makes it possible to define the authorisation for a particular Tessera instance, ensuring it is only allowed to access the secrets that it needs.  Additionally these credentials can be configured to expire after a certain number of uses or length of time.

Finally, TLS should be enabled on the Vault server to ensure secure communication between Vault and Tessera.  The necessary TLS certificates and keys should be included in the Tessera start-up config.

The Tessera wiki provides more details on the exact configuration and environment variables to provide:

- https://github.com/jpmorganchase/tessera/wiki/Setting-up-a-Hashicorp-Vault
- https://github.com/jpmorganchase/tessera/wiki/Keys#4-hashicorp-vault-key-pairs

Comment: Thank you Chris for the confirmation.